# Converting GTK 1.2 glade XML file to something glade can now read

Tags: gtk3, glade

In [old project](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnopstree/) I wrote circa 2000 I have a [glade file](https://sourceforge.net/p/gnopstree/code/ci/master/tree/gnopstree.glade) that I would like to convert to something glade can now read, and I will use in PyGtk. I have scoured SO for similar questions and see things for the code changes, but I am just interested right now in converting the glade file.

When I run *gtk-builder-convert* I get Python traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/gtk-builder-convert", line 799, in <module>
     sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
      File "/usr/bin/gtk-builder-convert", line 787, in main
   conv.parse_file(input_filename)
  File "/usr/bin/gtk-builder-convert", line 162, in parse_file
    self._parse()
  File "/usr/bin/gtk-builder-convert", line 234, in _parse
   assert glade_iface, ("Badly formed XML, there is "
AssertionError: Badly formed XML, there is no <glade-interface> tag.
```

which is indeed true. The file starts:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<GTK-Interface>
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the information from ebassi, what I wound up doing is running *libglade-convert* to get this to gtk 2.0 and then *gtk-builder-convert* to go the rest of the way. Of course there were lots of errors and it is imperfect, but its a start.

Answer (score 2):

If your XML file starts with `GTK-Interface` then it means it you were using GTK+ 1.2.

It's very unlikely you can mechanically transform such an old Glade file into something that can be used with modern API — even if you constrain yourself to the legacy 2.0 version of the GTK+ API. Your UI description will contain deprecated properties, signals, and classes — and there is no direct, 1:1 mapping for those.

The last time the XML format for the UI definition was changed was 2007, with the introduction of [GtkBuilder](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkBuilder.html), but the format was heavily based on the Glade XML for GTK+ 2.0, to the point that a simple mechanical script like `gtk-builder-convert` could transform the older format into the new one. Your XML predates even that.

Answer (score 0):

It worked on Linux for me using Gtk3+ and Glade3+ installed from conda by following steps.

1. Open your Gtk1+ older glade XML file designed in Glade1+ user interface in **Glade3+ user interface**.
2. Click on **Save** button in **Glade3+ user interface**.
3. Open terminal to conda activate **gtk-builder-convert infile outfile**.

Good Luck!

Comment: The file I am trying to convert is https://sourceforge.net/p/gnopstree/code/ci/master/tree/gnopstree.glade. Are you saying that you are able to convert this? When I run the gtk-build-convert using python 3.7.4, it now complains about inconsistant tabs and spaces: `TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation`. If you can convert this file, I'd be grateful. However the project goes back 19 years and I haven't looked at this in 4 or so years.